# p-value is always the same in R (2.2e-16)

Tags: r, chi-squared, p-value

I am trying to find correlations among some variables. But whatever pair of variables I choose, the p-value is ALWAYS "2.2e-16". That number is the lowest the machine can handle, so it is basically zero, but I don't think it should be so small.

So I guess something is wrong, but I just can't see what it could be. The code I am using is:

```
> BaseVals <- read.table ("C:/Users/BasePurchases.csv", sep=";", row.names=1 , header=T) 
> attach(BaseVals)
> tbl = table(BaseVals$AvgValue,BaseVals$TimeSinceLastPurchase)
> chisq.test(tbl)
```

And the result is:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tbl X-squared = 732.43, df = 9, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

And the values of *tbl* are:

```
                  1-Up to 30 days 2-30 to 45 days 3-45 to 60 days 4-More than 60 days
  1-Up to $120             2048           2560           2176              1664
  2-$120 to R$350          1408           2432           2560              1792
  3-$350 to R$850          1152           1664           1152              1152
  4-$850 and more          1280           1024            640              1280
```

Comment: You're not testing correlation, you're doing a chi square test of independence (which is probably correct for this kind of discrete data). With such a large sample size, and the kinds of differences I can see from eyeballing the data, I'm not surprised that you consistently see very small p-values. If you're still convinced something is wrong, see if you can come up with an example and explain exactly why it seems off, based on what you know about the test.

Comment: First: unrelated, but don't use `attach()` ! Google to see why. Second: try storing the result of chisq.test using `csq <- chisq.test(tbl)`, then note what `csq$p.value` returns. Note that the test says your p-value is _less than_ 2.2e-16.